# Sketch a curve given parametrically by $x=2t-4t^3$ and $t^2-3t^4$

Tags: plane-curves, parametric

I am unable to see how to eliminate $t$. Wolfram Alpha fails at it too.

$$x=2t-4t^3$$ $$y=t^2-3t^4$$

I can guess that the curve is a polynomial equation so in principle I can write this as

$$w_1 x^4 +w_2 x^3 +w_3 x^2 +w_4 x +w_5 y^3 +w_6 y^2 +w_7 y +w_8=0$$

for the powers of $t$ to cancel when plugged in I am determine all these $w's$ by substituting the $t's$ for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and setting each of the new coefficients of the $t$'s $C_i(w_1,...w_8)$ to zero individually. I have my curve determined if I put each of the $C_i(w_1,...w_8)=0$ and solve for the $w$'s.

All this was in principle, but this is like an examination question so there must be a clever manipulation/way, which I have been unable to find.

Comment: Since I know the source of the problem, and there is no obvious way to eliminate $t$... may I suggest creating a table and plotting points? As a polynomial, we know it will act somewhat predictably, so it shouldn't take too many points to understand what the graph "looks like." It does say "sketch," after all ;)

Comment: Lol! That's a good idea. Ill try to plot a few points and get a good polynomial to fit. Btw, after seeing the actual answer I realize that the method ive posted is also wrong for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My opinion is that you should not try to eliminate $t$ at all. Instead, you should think about how $x$ and $y$ behave as $t$ varies, find some important points such as the critical points with respect to $x$ and $y$, and try to sketch the graph from that information.

$x=2t-4t^3$ means that as $t$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, $x$ decreases from $\infty$ to a local minimum of $-\sqrt{8/27}$ at $t = -1/\sqrt{6}$, then rises to $\sqrt{8/27}$ at $t = 1/\sqrt{6}$, then falls again to $-\infty$.

$y=t^2-3t^4$ means that $y$ starts and ends at $-\infty$, with local maxima of $1/12$ when $t = \pm 1/\sqrt{6}$, and a local minimum of $0$ at $t = 0$.

Interestingly, $t = \pm 1/\sqrt{6}$ is a critical point for both $x$ and $y$, both of whose derivatives change sign, so the curve forms a cusp at that point.

That's enough information to follow the curve as $t$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$: it comes in from the bottom right quadrant $(\infty,-\infty)$, goes upward and leftward till it hits the cusp $(-\sqrt{8/27},1/12)$, upon which it turns around, passing smoothly through $(0,0)$ where its tangent is horizontal, until it reaches the second cusp $(\sqrt{8/27},1/12)$, and then turns around a second time and exits at the bottom left towards $(-\infty,-\infty)$.

This is consistent with [the plot arising from Juan Joder's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+27x%5E4-4x%5E2%2836y+1%29+16y%284y+1%29%5E2=0).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't know how to do it in an exam, but using a Gröbner basis routine such as that in *Mathematica* easily gives the implicit Cartesian equation

$$27x^4-4x^2(36y+1)+16y(4y+1)^2=0$$

Comment: In *Mathematica*: `GroebnerBasis[{x == 2t - 4t^3, y == t^2 - 3t^4}, {x, y}, t]`

Comment: I googled for the grobner basis algorithm but I got a lot of stuff about polynomial rings etc which I have no background on. Do you know if there is preferrably a method or a specific algorithm for it that I can use to atleast get approximate numerical values?

Comment: Well, internally most computing systems like *Mathematica* or Maple use Gröbner bases to eliminate variables anyway. I believe there were a few questions on this asked on this very site, but I can't be bothered to search. As for getting numerical values, you're lucky you already have a parametric equation to begin with; the problem of turning an implicit Cartesian equation into a (practical!) set of parametric equations is quite harder.

Comment: As for easing the task of sketching, note that $y(t)$ is an *even* function; it stands to reason that your graph ought to be symmetric about the y-axis (or, as soon as you eliminate the parameter $t$, $x$ will always occur as even powers). Use that to simplify the task of sketching.

Answer (score 2):

Natural points for sketching include: when $x=0$, giving $t = 0 \text{ or } \pm 1/\sqrt{2}$ and so $y = 0 \text{ or } -1/4$; and when $y=0$, giving $t = 0 \text{ or } \pm 1/\sqrt{3}$ and so $x = 0 \text{ or } \pm 2/\sqrt{27}$.  So these four points suggest something interesting is going on near the origin.

Just drawing the curve parametrically using Excel gives something like [image: large scale curve]

but zooming in gives the more interesting [image]

largely matching Rahul Narain's answer and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=27+x%5E4-144+x%5E2+y-4+x%5E2+256+y%5E3+128+y%5E2+16+y+=0)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at Gibson's book "Elementary Geometry of Algebraic Curves",
in particular discussions on page 9 and page 178.

As to your problem at hand, you just consider x and y as parameters in equations
$f(t) =-4t^3 +2t -x =0$
and 
$g(t) =-3t^4 +t^2 -y =0$.
When x and y are chosen properly there is a value of t solving both equations.
That means there is a common root for both polyomials. So to find the relationship
between x and y you need only to solve the "resultant" of these two polynomials
f(t) and g(t). This resultant is a determinat involving x and y which vanishes
if and only if there is such a common root. Hence the resultant $R(f,g)=0$ gives the
desired equation relating x and y.

As to your original method, you overlooked the possibility that the equation relating x and y might have monomials like $xy$ and $x^2y$. Thus it is destined to fail.

If my computation is correct, the final equation should be
$$\frac{27}{64}x^4-\frac{1}{16}x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^2y+4y(y+\frac{1}{4})^2=0.$$